# Get language-specific name using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to retrieve language-specific name for a user, using Graph API?

Comment: "A language-specific name is an extra name you can add to your profile (timeline), so people can see your name in a language they understand". 
It's like additional name for some locallized versions.

Answer (score 1):

I am finding answer of this question. And finally, I got a solution for this.

step 1. First, request below api

> /v2.4/me?fields=id,name,locale

then, you received locale information of the user.

step 2. Now, request below api

> /v2.4/me?fields=id,name?locale="locale received in step 1"

If you use android facebook sdk like me, then write code like below.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("fields", "id,name,locale");
//bundle.putString("locale", "ko_KR");
new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/me",
        bundle,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "response -> " + response.getRawResponse());
            }
        }
).executeAsync();
```

"me" can be converted into "". I tested in the graph api(v2.4). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that’s what you mean, but there’s a field called "name_format" in the [FQL user table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/):

> name_format : string : The user's name formatted to correctly handle Chinese, Japanese, Korean ordering.

Edit: No, sorry, I’m just realizing this only gives you something like "name_format": "{first} {last}", so that first and last name can be printed out in the right order.